# How to render a table in React by using Blueprint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, blueprint

I'm trying to render a very simple table with React and the [Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6IeU.png) UI toolkit.

The [documentation](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.table-js) relative to the `Table` component is quite simple, but it seems like my code doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as Blueprint from '@blueprintjs/core';
import { Cell, Column, Table } from '@blueprintjs/table';

const renderCell = (rowIndex: number) => {
    return <Cell>{`$${(rowIndex * 10).toFixed(2)}`}</Cell>
};

var myTable = (
  <Table numRows={10}>
    <Column name="Dollars" renderCell={renderCell}/>
  </Table>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  myTable,
  document.getElementById('myTable')
);
```

The image below shows what I get. How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you including `blueprint.css` and `blueprint-table.css` on your page? The Table won't render correctly without its stylesheets!

Comment: I have the same problem, the suggested include is not working with a boiler plate that uses webpack, and require() won't include the css either due to the @ in the @blueprintjs module name, any ideas?

Comment: Interesting...this is not in the [table install docs](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table-js.installation). For me, the file was in `node_modules/@blueprintjs/table/dist/table.css` (notice the different css filename).

Answer (score 3):

I had to include this line in my css file (using webpack setup by create-react-app):

```
@import '~@blueprintjs/table/dist/table.css';
```

Answer (score 3):

For me,

```
yarn add @blueprintjs/core @blueprintjs/table
```

Then using a relative path from my react component file

```
import { Cell, Column, Table } from '@blueprintjs/table'

import '../../node_modules/@blueprintjs/table/lib/css/table.css'
```

Comment: For blueprint 3 + react: import '@blueprintjs/table/lib/css/table.css'

Answer (score -3):

import '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css'